# Alternative to dynamically creating elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a Pinterest style column layout, similar to what something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) or [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com) would provide, but in an AngularJS directive. Because the number of columns will vary as the window size changes, my plan was to dynamically create more column elements as needed. However, reading online, creating elements in JavaScript seems like bad practice in AngularJS. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: never used it, but looks like there's an angular masonry directive - http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I don't actually want to use Masonry; I'm looking for something much lighter weight and I'd prefer to create it myself to get it a bit more tailored to what I'm doing. I'm mostly curious if in general there is a better way of dynamically creating elements in Angular without doing it in JS. Although I think I might have an idea with templates and ngRepeat which I'm testing now; I'll post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: Creating elements in JavaScript seems like bad practice in AngularJS? Actually that is where Angular excels. Google 'dynamic elements angular' and you will find some good solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't we be using templates and directives instead? Wouldn't that be better than `element.append("<div>Great Element</div>");`, or am I incorrect?

Comment: You can use a template or just pure Javascript to create the element inside the directive. The template is probably a preferred route as it is more readable and easier to maintain. However the JS in AngularJS does stand for Javascript after all. Even when using a template you are still using JS to "create" the element. The biggest gotcha would be doing any sort of DOM manipulation outside of a directive.